# From a pure personal health perspective how bad are some non strictly vegan/vegetarian products?

Tags: veganism, health, plant-based

So I'm curious about a plant based diet for health purposes, and though the by-product of that step may be great for animal welfare, environment etc.

How committed should I be about products like Wine, or even egg based pasta or things that may contain small amounts of non-vegan products (as part of their ingredients, rather than "made in a factory that processes X").

I may still buy leather goods, or meat based dog food (for the dog!), so avoiding non vegan food on an ethical standpoint would be a bit of a moot point!

Is there a linear scale of health benefits the more animal products you cut down on? e.g. is a 99% vegan who eats an egg a week 99% as healthy as a 100% vegan.. Or does that egg screw you over and you're back to 50% as good.

Comment: I'm voting to close your question as too broad since it asks generally "how unhealthy are non-vegan products?" Asking specifically about the health implications of consuming a single non-vegan food or category of food (eg dairy) might be off-topic here! But maybe you mean to ask something like how significant will the difference in health benefit be between a vegan and almost vegan diet? See [Are there any studies that show differences in health benefits between a low meat eater flexitarian and other vegetarians types?](//vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/q/669)

Comment: Fair point.. I guess another way of looking at it is asking: is there a linear scale of health benefits the more animal products you cut down on? e.g. is a 99% vegan who eats an egg a week 99% as healthy as a 100% vegan.. Or does that egg screw you over and you're back to 50% as good..

Comment: Ah ok, I see what you mean. If you can edit to clarify a little, that will be great. I'm retracting my vote as I can imagine suitable answers. Thanks :)

Comment: I think this is too broad. There's no way you'll get an all-encompasing list of "this stuff is really unhealthy". You might manage a top-ten most unhealthy non-vegn foods list (at the top of which I expect you'd find a [deep-fried mars bar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep-fried_Mars_bar) or a [twinkie-wiener sandwich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22Weird_Al%22_Yankovic#UHF)), but I don't think you'll get anything exhaustive.

Comment: I think your blanket premise that a vegan diet is more healthy than a mixed diet is wrong. Too many factors go into what constitutes a [healthy diet](https://health.gov/dietaryguidelines/2015/).

Answer (score 2):

First off: bravo for choosing to go vegan. This choice is *absolutely great* for animals and the environment!

There is a big difference between being vegan and being plant-pased, which I will try to simplify. Basically, being vegan doesn't necessarily mean that you're eating plant-based, and eating plant-based doesn't necessarily mean that you're vegan.

Plant-based diets are about eating as healthily as possible - which is what leads us to eat whole plant foods exclusively, and exclude animal products and processed foods. However, people who follow a plant-based lifestyle may still wear fur or attend circuses - which vegans oppose due to animal exploitation.

Veganism is about causing as little suffering as possible - which is what leads us to eat foods that exclude animal products. Vegans may consume non-healthy vegan or "accidentally vegan" processed foods, though, such as Oreos. Oreos are not a whole food and would not be considered plant-based.

If you want to protect animals and our planet, go vegan. If you'd also like to protect your health, go vegan and eat a plant-based diet focused on nutritious whole foods.

Happy Herbivore has a [post](https://happyherbivore.com/2013/07/what-is-plant-based-diet-difference-from-vegan/) that goes into more details.

I hope that helps!